# How to split strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following input:

```
Data
-----
A,10
A,20
A,30
B,23
B,45
```

Expected output:

```
col1  Col2
----  -----
A      10
A      20
A      30
B      23
B      45
```

How can I split the string to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT substring(data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',data)-1) col1,
substring(data, CHARINDEX(',',data)+1, LEN(data)) col2
FROM table
```

Comment: More info CHARINDEX http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx SUBSTRING http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: @nikrts sorry i posted my answer which is almost identical to you but i didnt copy your.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this solution, Wouldn't it be more appropiate to use 'left, 'right + reverse' with new logic instead of 'substring' ?

Comment: I assumed that lenght can be variable eg. AB,51 in any other case I agree with @vlad

Comment: check if if (CHARINDEX(',', data) > 0) to not get an error if there is no splitting character

Answer (score 5):

I know the points has already been given, going to post it anyway because i think it is slightly better

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (DATA VARCHAR(20))

INSERT @t VALUES ('A,10');INSERT @t VALUES ('AB,101');INSERT @t VALUES ('ABC,1011')

SELECT LEFT(DATA, CHARINDEX(',',data) - 1) col1, 
RIGHT(DATA, LEN(DATA) - CHARINDEX(',', data)) col2
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 3):

if the values in column 1 are always one character long, and the values in column 2 are always 2, you can use the [SQL Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [SQL Right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) functions:

```
SELECT LEFT(data, 1) col1, RIGHT(data, 2) col2
FROM <table_name>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @string nvarchar(50)
set @string='AA,12'

select substring(@string,1,(charindex(',',@string)-1) ) as col1 
, substring(@string,(charindex(',',@string)+1),len(@string) ) as col2![my sql server image which i tried.][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is so easy, you can take it by below query:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATA, CHARINDEX(',',DATA)-1) col1,RIGHT(Data,LEN(DATA)-(CHARINDEX(',',DATA))) col2 from Table
```