# SQL server code to split 2 delimited columns into rows using the elements' order

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Table name: D_order

```
OrderID    OrderName    
11,12        A:B
13,14        C:D
```

Output required

```
OrderID      OrderName    
11               A
12               B
13               C
14               D
```

Comment: Don't store data this way to begin with. That breaks the most basic design principle the 1st Normal Form. Even when you split those values, the server will have to scan the entire table because no index will contain the actual ID values, only the full strings. Forget about unique checks too. That's not a relational model disadvantage, that's just a design bug. Just *don't* do it.

Comment: Hi @DhruvRed, can you show us the code you have tried so far ? Cheers!

Comment: BTW the "expected" results are arbitrary - where's `11 - B` ? By what logic was that pair eliminated? Even if you used a database with array support, there's no order relation between the values of different arrays. Apart from that, there are a *lot* of essentially duplicate questions that show how to split strings. Supported SQL Server versions (even 2014 has gone out of mainstream support) provide `STRING_SPLIT`. Restricting values based on element order though is going to be a real pain, both in code and performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try a JSON based approach. Just transform the data into valid JSON arrays and parse these arrays with `OPENJSON()`. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, and the `key` column holds the index of the element in these arrays. With this approach you can parse more than two elements.

Starting from SQL Server 2022, the `STRING_SPLIT()` function supports an optional third parameter (`enable_ordinal`). The parameter is an `int` or `bit` expression that serves as a flag to enable or disable the ordinal output column and a value of `1` enables the ordinal column.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   OrderID nvarchar(100),    
   OrderName nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (OrderID, OrderName)
VALUES   
   (N'11,12', N'A:B'),
   (N'13,14', N'C:D'),
   (N'15,16,17,18', N'E:F:G:H')
```

Statement with `OPENJSON()`:

```
SELECT j1.[value] AS OrderId, j2.[value] AS OrderName
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'[', d.OrderId, N']')) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(d.OrderName, N':', N'","'), N'"]')) j2
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Statement with `STRING_SPLIT()`:

```
SELECT s1.[value] AS OrderId, s2.[value] AS OrderName
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.OrderId, N',', 1) s1
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.OrderName, N':', 1) s2
WHERE s1.[ordinal] = s2.[ordinal]
```

Result:

```
-----------------
OrderId OrderName
-----------------
11      A
12      B
13      C
14      D
15      E
16      F
17      G
18      H
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function might help
check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493616/6631280

or Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f54fd/10

```
;WITH tmp(OrderID, OrderName, String) AS
    (
        SELECT
            OrderID,
            OrderName,
            LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
            STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
        FROM Testdata
        UNION all

        SELECT
            OrderID,
            OrderName,
            LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1),
            STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
        FROM tmp
        WHERE
            String > ''
    )

    SELECT
        OrderID,
        OrderName, 
    FROM tmp
    ORDER BY OrderID
```

Comment: It won't - for starters, that's the slowest way possible to split strings in *unsupported* versions of SQL Server, In supported versions, `STRING_SPLIT` is available. Second, there's no order guarantee and the OP wants values matched by *element order*, not OrderID

Answer (score 0):

You should split the strings and make union. I used approach for spliting string described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619810/how-to-split-strings-in-sql-server/6619841).

The code:

```
SELECT substring(OrderId, 1, CHARINDEX(',',OrderId)-1) OrderId,
       substring(OrderName, 1, CHARINDEX(':',OrderName)-1) OrderName
  FROM YourDataTable

UNION ALL

SELECT substring(OrderId, CHARINDEX(',',OrderId)+1, LEN(OrderId)),
   substring(OrderName, CHARINDEX(':',OrderName)+1, LEN(OrderName))
  FROM YourDataTable
```

This works only for the formatting in the sample data.